# Searching String Array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have this string array....

```
public static final String[][] cardNames = {
        {"10","Blah"},
        ...
}
```

The data structure is the same for all records below that and all have a unique number value at the beginning (not related to their index). Id like to quickly find a record by that value without having to loop through the entire thing. Is that possible?

Comment: Seems like you'd benefit from using a `Map`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), since it is a `unique number value` you can use that as a **key** and use the `get method` of the `HashMap` to directly get the value without iterating on it.

**sample:**

```
    Map<String,String> s = new HashMap<String,String>();
    s.put("10","Blah"); //to put the data

    if(s.get("10") != null)
      s.get("10"); //to get the data without iterating.
```

If your value is a String array

```
    Map<String,String[]> s = new HashMap<String,String[]>();
    s.put("10",new String[]{"Blah","Blah2"}); //to put the String data array


    if(s.get("10") != null)
    {
        String s1 = s.get("10")[0]; //to get the data in index 0 without iterating.
        String s2 = s.get("10")[1]; //to get the data in index 1 without iterating.
    }
```

Comment: you can do `Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>()` since Java 7 :)

Comment: @Reimeus :)) yes indeed.

Answer (score 8):

You should store this data in a `Map<String,String>` or `Map<Integer,String>` (since your keys are numerical Strings). That would make searching trivial.

Then searching for a value with a given unique key would be as simple as :

```
if (map.containsKey("504")) {
    String value = map.get("504");
}
```

And the search would be performed in expected `O(1)` time.